# How to know color in Google Maps Android API?

Tags: android, google-maps

How  can I  know what exact color of this point is?

[image]

Where  can I find it?

Comment: If you only need that color, then use some color picker extension to know that color. "#E9E5DC"

Answer (score 0):

You could take a screenshot:

```
// create bitmap screen capture
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Then just read the pixel colour from the bitmap:

```
 int colour = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Open GoogleMaps with browser.
Go to "View Page Source"

Find it.